# Database / Software pattern for recommending items with similar taste?

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc-3, recommendation-engine

I'd like to build a recommendation system on my site so people can "like" certain things, and then display other things that other people liked as well. A "recommendation" system if you will.

Examples:

- Amazon - shows items other people liked as well.
- Newegg - shows items other people bought together.
- 9gag - shows pictures liked by other people.

I'm new to this sort of software design and literally have no idea on where to start. Would love some suggestions and reading material and even better a pattern that has already been cooked up by smarter people.

My items will be either "liked" or "neutral" (user didn't do anything). No fine tuned rating system for the item, I assume this would simplify the needed algorithm.

My platform is C# with ASP.Net MVC3 with MSSQL 2008 as the backend; if that is relevant to the discussion.

Comment: Amazon and Newegg have the benifit of having volumes of data to collect. Think of it as behavioral targeting. They can record everything a person views and ultimately buys and pair your interests (by shopping history or view history) to their large amount of data and then show you the things that other people "liked" who matchs your behaviors. While this info doesnt tell you how to set it up it gives you some idea of how to do something similar. To start your comparisions are going to be terrible because you won't have enough behavorial info but as your data grows so will the accuracy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Building recommendation based algorithms usually do not follow a particular set of design patterns...they vary based on your application's domain...

If you are not aware of the concepts/mechanics of these kind of algorithms, these algorithms are build based on the concepts like Collective Intelligence, Machine Learning, Crowd Sourcing etc...

[Programming Collective Intelligence](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596529325) is by far the best reading you can get...this book should give you a very good perspective on how to build an algorithm for your requirement. But unfortunately, this book uses python...for code examples...but still the concepts are very helpful...

Answer (score 0):

You may want to read a book which describes this problem space like [Algorithms of the Intelligent Web](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1933988665) or the older [Programming Collective Intelligence](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596529321.do).